# android listview using soap calling

Tags: java, android, listview, soap, android-adapter

Hi i have to develop one listview app in android using soap calling.here i wish to run the app means the orderid and status is displayed here.here i have to click any order from list means the status is displayed next activity.

But the orderid and status is displayed on listview successfully..but here faced some problem...the orderid and status is displayed following format:

```
1
---------
F2
----------
Q3
----------
P
-----------
```

But i wish to display below format:

```
1 F
---------
2 Q
---------
3 P
---------
```

This is my **android code**:

```
public class RetailerActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/customerData1";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "customerData1";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8089/XcartLogin/services/RetailerWs?wsdl";
private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        SoapPrimitive s = response;
        String str = s.toString();
        String resultArr[] = str.split("&");
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,resultArr));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String s2= getIntent().getStringExtra("status");


                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);

                 in.putExtra(KEY_STATUS, s2);


                 startActivity(in);                 

            }
        });     
    }


    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

This is my **webservice code**:

```
public class RetailerWs {
public String customerData1(){
String customerInfo = "";
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart-432pro","root","");
  //Find customer information where the customer ID is maximum
PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xcart_orders");
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

 while(result.next()){
customerInfo = customerInfo + result.getString("orderid") + "&" + result.getString("status");
  //Here "&"s are added to the return string. This is help to split the string in Android application
 }
 }

 catch(Exception exc){
 System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
 }

return customerInfo;
 }

 }
```

this is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your webservice code line:

```
customerInfo = customerInfo + result.getString("orderid") + "&" + result.getString("status");
```

to:

```
customerInfo = customerInfo 
    + result.getString("orderid") 
    + " "   // this to separate order id from status
    + result.getString("status") 
    + "&" ; // this is where you split in your android code
```

So, for your sample input

```
1 F
2 Q
3 P
```

you now generate the string "1 F&2 Q&3 P" instead of "1&F2&Q3&P".

After that, I suggest you to think some better way to pass data between your components.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use XML Like this-- Try this Does it work for u

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" android:height="1sp">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="1sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:paddingLeft="2px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingRight="2px">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:fadingEdge="none" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

List View To Fill You Data -- it has the same size u want for your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/lv"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textColor="#000000">
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/orderid"   android:textColor="#7E3517" android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:width="1dip" android:gravity="left"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/Status"   android:textColor="#7E3517" android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:width="1dip" android:gravity="left"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/Status"   android:textColor="#7E3517" android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:width="1dip" android:gravity="right"/>      <TextView android:id="@+id/Status"   android:textColor="#7E3517" android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:width="1dip" android:gravity="right"/>      <TextView android:id="@+id/Status"   android:textColor="#7E3517" android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:width="1dip" android:gravity="right"/>      <TextView android:id="@+id/Status"   android:textColor="#7E3517" android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:width="1dip" android:gravity="right"/>      <TextView android:id="@+id/Status"   android:textColor="#7E3517" android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:width="1dip" android:gravity="right"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can also Summary Adapter to file your list View